# launch ... to/into space

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, collocations

Normally, I expect the verb "launch" to go with "**into** space." But I saw the following:

> Three rookie astronauts aboard SpaceX’s Crew-3 mission for NASA just launched **to** space for the first time. They’ve tipped the number of people to have gone to space to over 600, according to a tally maintained by NASA. [Source](https://www.nytimes.com/live/2021/11/10/science/nasa-spacex-launch)

> The NS-19 mission brings Blue Origin to 14 people launched **to** space in 2021, a year that has seen a flurry of private human spaceflight activity. [Source](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/12/11/watch-jeff-bezos-blue-origin-ns-19-live-first-six-passenger-crew.html)

> The entire lab and all its equipment launched **to** space a little more than 40 years ago on May 14, 1973, aboard the last Saturn V rocket ever to travel in space. [Source](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/history/stations.html)

Why is "to" used? Does the choice reflect some conception of outer space?

Comment: I don't know why they used that, but it's [extremely uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=launched+to+space%2C+launched+into+space&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claunched%20to%20space%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claunched%20into%20space%3B%2Cc0) - maybe the author is not a native English speaker. I would consider it odd/strange/non-native.

Comment: Those are native sources, though.

Comment: Do you know the author's nationality, or first language?  NASA employs people from all over the world. Also, even native speakers are not necessarily good writers.

Comment: The NASA article's author is Tracy McMahan, who I assume to be a native.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the author. She has a LinkedIn page.

Comment: That'd be a rather trivial thing to bother a space scientist with.

Comment: Perhaps "launched to space" is NASA parlance/jargon?  There are so many possibilities.

Comment: In that connection, I found some pop science websites also use "launch ... to space."

Answer (score 1):

- "Into" implies the subject arrived in space (and stayed there for a significant amount of time), whereas "to" simply emphasizes direction.

  In your second quote, for example, the flight only took 11 minutes and, while having reached 100 km — a theoretical border between the Earth's atmosphere and 'space' — it was never intended for the rocket to go *into* space:

  > The rocket launched from Blue Origin’s private facility in West Texas, and reached above 100 kilometers (or more than 340,000 feet altitude) before returning to Earth safely a few minutes later.
- Another interpretation, and one that seems more likely to me, is that all the subjects of your example sentences (i.e. "*three rookie astronauts*", "*14 people*", and "*the entire lab and all its equipment*" respectively) were ***inside objects** that were launched **into** space*, so as to distinguish the meaning from these entities being launched into space as-is (like how in science fiction the dead are often ejected *into* space).

  In short: people (and objects) are launched *to space* inside spacecrafts, but spacecrafts are launched *into space*.